# Why does Windows 7 (32) install a driver for a non existing Bluetooth device?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

Device manager shows a Bluetooth adapter and claims "this device is working properly". I can uninstall it but Windows keeps detecting it and re-installs the driver automatically.

[image: device manager]

But there is no such adapter. The PC is a laptop (acer aspire one 756-987) that comes with Bluetooth in some editions but not with this one. I installed W7 myself.

It wouldn't be a big deal if it weren't keeping a real Bluetooth radio (USB) from getting to work.

Here is how it looks with the USB device plugged in:

[image]

It says: This device cannot start (code 10)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound: see link, but it does show only what I wrote

Comment: Do both of those devices in your screenshot (the Adapter and the Enumerator) show up when your USB BT adapter isn't plugged in?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Yes and both are "working properly"

Comment: Ok, neat. :)  What are the Hardware IDs of the "Generic Bluetooth Adapter" (Properties -> Details tab -> Hardware IDs)?

Comment: Maybe they screwed up and installed a bluetooth module on that model.

Comment: Hardware ID of the Generic Bluetooth Adapter: USB\VID_0489&PID_E04E&REV0001

Comment: I disabled Bluetooth Support Service but they keep popping up ...

Answer (score 1):

Found out what is going on. Below is a review of the device that you listed you have.

https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-One-756-Subnotebook.81609.0.html

> The rest of the interfaces are the standard minimum and can also be found in a netbook. The Ethernet connector (RJ45, Gigabit LAN) is obligatory, despite the fact that most users have already forgotten that the "Internet" can be used via cable. The Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter supports Draft N and also incorporates the Bluetooth 4.0 module. For transfers of large data in the home network, we recommend the RJ45 cable and a gigabit switch.

In this passage it lists that you have a AR5BWB222 WIFI card installed.
This card has Bluetooth integrated into it.

So windows is detecting the Bluetooth device correctly but is more than likely installing the wrong drivers or that the antenna in the laptop don't support Bluetooth  causing the issue. The simplest fix would be to disable the device instead of uninstalling it

Right click on the generic Bluetooth adapter
Select properties
Go to the driver tab
Select Disable driver

Reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: Impressive research! You answered my question. However, even when disabled it still prevents the USB-Bluetooth dongle from installing properly. Perhaps Windows is not capabale of handling two Bluetooth devices.

Comment: In the meantime I installed Windows 10 and guess what, now I can use even the internal Bluetooth simply by switching it on in the network center. Didn't see that option in Win 7. The laptop manual explicitly talks about a hardware switch which is not present in this model. Thanks again for your help!